# Select the last record in each group (With inner join)

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, group-by

There is a 'Events' table that contains data as shown below:

```
 no  | qty | events
----------------------
001  | 10  | Printed
004  | 10  | Printed
007  | 10  | Printed
004  | 2   | Reprint
```

and There is a 'Numbers' table that contains data as shown below:

```
start_no |   no   | serial | expiry_date
--------------------------------------------
001      |  001   | 9311   | 2019-03-03
001      |  002   | 9312   | 2019-03-03
001      |  003   | 9313   | 2019-03-03
004      |  004   | 9314   | 2019-03-06
004      |  005   | 9315   | 2019-03-06
004      |  006   | 9316   | 2019-03-06
007      |  007   | 9317   | 2019-03-10
007      |  008   | 9318   | 2019-03-10
```

This is the query that I use:

```
SELECT start_no, n.no, n.serial, expiry_date, qty
FROM Numbers n
INNER JOIN Events e ON n.start_no = e.no
WHERE events='Printed'
```

I need query will return the following result:

```
start_no |   no   | serial | expiry_date
--------------------------------------------
001      |  003   | 9313   | 2019-03-03
004      |  006   | 9316   | 2019-03-06
007      |  008   | 9318   | 2019-03-10
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ise `row_number()`

```
select * from
(
SELECT start_no, n.no, w.serial, expiry_date, qty,
row_number() over(partition by start_no order by w.serial desc) as rn
FROM Numbers n INNER JOIN Events e ON n.start_no = e.no
WHERE events='Printed'
)A where rn=1
```

Answer (score 0):

use `row_number()` window function

```
select * from 
(SELECT start_no, n.no, w.serial, expiry_date, qty
,row_number() over(partition by start_no order by no desc) rn
FROM Numbers n
INNER JOIN Events e ON n.start_no = e.no
WHERE events='Printed'
) a where a.rn=1
```